# Encode and Decode with Base64 and Pickle

Tags: python, base64, pickle

I need to pickle a dict, then Base64 encode this before transporting the data via an API call..

The receiver should decode the Base64 data and the pickle load it back in to a proper dict.

Issue is that it fails on the decoding of it, it doesn't seem to be the same binary data after Decode the Base64 data, hence the Pickle fails.

What am I missing?

```
import pickle
import base64
import json

def publishData():
   testDict = {}
   testDict['testKey1'] = [1,2,3]
   testDict['testKey2'] = [4,5,6]
   #Dump the dict to pickle file
   with open("test.pkl","wb") as f:
      pickle.dump(testDict, f)
   #Read the pickle
   with open("test.pkl", "rb") as openfile:
      data = openfile.read() #Read the raw pickle (binary)
   print("publishData - Pickle read : {}".format(data))
   #Base64 encode it to ensure formatting in JSON
   data = base64.b64encode(data)
   print("publishData - Base64 encoded : {}".format(data))
   #Create a json to be published via API
   publishJson = json.dumps({"payload":str(data)})
   print("publishData - Publish JSON : {}".format(publishJson))
   #Decode the data
   decodeData(publishJson)

def decodeData(publishJson):
   data = json.loads(publishJson)
   payload = data['payload']
   payload = base64.b64decode(payload)
   print("decodeData - Payload decoded: {}".format(payload))
   print(pickle.loads(payload))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   publishData()
```

Output:

```
publishData - Pickle read : b'\x80\x04\x95/\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\x08testKey1\x94]\x94(K\x01K\x02K\x03e\x8c\x08testKey2\x94]\x94(K\x04K\x05K\x06eu.'
publishData - Base64 encoded : b'gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg=='
publishData - Publish JSON : {"payload": "b'gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg=='"}
decodeData - Payload decoded: b'n\x00\x12T\xbc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf6P\xa20!\xd1\x95\xcd\xd1-\x95\xe4\xc6QvP\xa1,\x05,\t,\r\x960!\xd1\x95\xcd\xd1-\x95\xe4\xcaQvP\xa1,\x11,\x15,\x19\x95\xd4\xb8'

_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'n'.
```

Comment: `pickle` between different versions of Python is not guaranteed to work; are you running the same version on both ends?

Comment: Thanks for input, the code is being executed in one go (the example above can be executed). So yes, same version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `data.decode()` or the equivalent `str(data, encoding='utf-8')` to convert the bytes to a valid base64-encoded string:

```py
# publishJson = json.dumps({"payload": str(data)})     # -
publishJson = json.dumps({"payload": data.decode())})  # +
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str:

> Passing a `bytes` object to `str()` without the `encoding` or `errors` arguments falls under the first case of returning the informal string representation

```py
print(data)                 #  b'gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg=='
print(repr(data))           #  b'gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg=='

print(str(data))            #  b'gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg=='
print(repr(str(data)))      # "b'gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg=='"

print(data.decode())        #    gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg==
print(repr(data.decode()))  #   'gASVLwAAAAAAAAB9lCiMCHRlc3RLZXkxlF2UKEsBSwJLA2WMCHRlc3RLZXkylF2UKEsESwVLBmV1Lg=='
```